# How do I customize error message for an invalid date format in Spring 3?

Tags: spring, date, validation, message

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I want to customize the error message displayed for an invalid date format in the java.util.Date fields in my model.  Here is the model …

```
public class ContractForm
{
    …
    private Date activationDate;

    private Date expirationDate;

    …

}
```

I have this setup in my properties bundle …

```
typeMismatch.ContractForm.activationDate=The activation date format should be of the form MM/dd/yyyy
typeMismatch.ContractForm.expirationDate=The expiration date format should be of the form MM/dd/yyyy
```

And I have registered a custom java.util.Date editor in my controller …

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Contract.DATE_FORMAT);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
    ...        
}
```

However, when I submit my form with an invalid date, I don't get my desired error message, instead getting something like, 'Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property activationDate; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "02012013"'

How do I get my desired error message?